# Quantmod R - candleChart - no colours

Tags: r, quantmod

I was using the code below to create a candle stick graph but I am ending with the picture below. Could anyone help?

```
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)


DIS <- get(getSymbols("DIS",src="google"))["2015::2017-02-15"] 
candleChart(DIS)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like there is any issue.  You're trying to plot years of data on what looks like a small display size, so the candles are too tiny to see.

What do you see if you plot a smaller chunk of the data?

`candleChart(DIS, subset = "2015-01/2015-02")`

You probably then see the candles clearly.

Either you need to expand the size of the output of your graphics device (blow up the image size), or subset to a smaller amount of data, to see the candles.

You might also find `chart_Series` useful too.

Comment: Thanks mate. It really worked! Really appreciate your feedback.